# Can JupyterHub Docker Spawner be configured to give different resource allocations to different users?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am using [JupyterHub's Docker Spawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner) to manage a Jupyter Notebook server for a set of users. The Docker Spawner allows setting resource allocations limits such as `cpu_limit` and `mem_limit`, but this configuration applies to all containers for all users. Is there any way to provide different resource allocations to different users when using this spawner?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you should use the `pre_spawn_hook`. [here docs](https://jupyterhub-dockerspawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html)

Define a hook function to be executed between the user login and the spawn of the docker container. In this function you can modify values for the current image to be spawned depending on the user logged in.

Here an example:

```
async def custom_pre_spawn_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name

    if username == 'tier1user':
        spawner.mem_limit = "4G"
        spawner.cpu_limit = 2

    else:
        spawner.mem_limit = "1G"
        spawner.cpu_limit = 1



c.Authenticator.enable_auth_state = True
c.DockerSpawner.pre_spawn_hook = custom_pre_spawn_hook
```

(Add this at the end of jupyterhub python config file)

You can find more information in general about jupyter and jupyterhub at [discourse.jupyter.org](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) and more specific about this question at [this nice post.](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/tailoring-spawn-options-and-server-configuration-to-certain-users/8449)